# Prove that the dual norm is also a norm.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $X=\Bbb R^m$ and $||\cdot||$ be an arbitrary norm on $X$. We define:

$$||y||_*=sup\{<x,y>:||x|| \le=1\}$$

where $|| , ||$ is an arbitary scalar product on X (we do not require the norm to be inherited from he scalar product, i.e., $||x||=\sqrt{<x,x>}$ does not necessarily hold.)

a) Assuming that $||y||_* < \infty$ and for all $y\in \Bbb R^m$, show that $||\cdot||_*$ is also a norm.

b) show that $$||x||_{**}=sup\{<x,y>: ||y||_*\le 1\}\le ||x||$$

a) To prove it is also a norm i need to show:

$||y||_*=0$ if and only if $y=0$. But here I already hit a obstacle.

Then if $y=0$ the dual norm doesn't have to be, does it? I mean the question does specify that it is an arbitrary norm.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: $\|y\|_*=0\iff \forall x\in \mathbb R: \|x\|\leq 1, \left<x,y\right>=0$. In particular, $\|y\|^2=\left<y,y\right>=0$ and thus $y=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if the scalar product is defined other than $<x,y>=x\cdot y$?

Comment: ah sorry i know thats the definition of scalar product. But I did see some examples where its defined differently like an integral. But they all involve some sort of multiplication. So i guess this works (thought of this before but was confused, thanks!)

Comment: $\left<\cdot ,\cdot \right>$ is some scalar product, not necessarily the Euclidian one...

Comment: btw how would you show homogeneity? $||cy||_*=sup <x,cy>=c\cdot sup<x,y>=...$ but then the sign of c matters here again, is that correct?

Comment: if $c$ is negative, $\sup\left<x,cy\right>=-c\sup\left<x,y\right>=|c|\sup...$

Comment: sorry i dont understand how that is true...if c is negative how is it that -c sup<x,y>=|c|<x,y>?

Comment: Forget about the scalar product. What is $\sup_{|x|\leq 1} cx$ for $c<0$ ?

Comment: Ah right, thank you so much!